# Google API: How can I check if the authentication was done successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

Using the Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 library in .NET, I am doing an OAuth2 authentication to the Google Analytics API, like this:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,  // view and manage your analytics data
                                             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,  // edit management actives
                                             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,   // manage users
                                             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly};     // View analytics data

UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                 , scopes
                                 , userName
                                 , CancellationToken.None
                                 , new DatabaseDataStore("Analytics")).Result;

AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Masterpiece"
});
```

The problem with this is that at the end, I don't know if the authentication was successful or not, as I don't see any way of getting any sort of message from this implementation. Normally, this works just fine and I can go on interrogating the API. However if I revoke the token that I have stored for this username, then this implementation will not tell me that the service was not authenticated and when I try to interrogate the API afterwards I get an error.

How in the world should I verify if the authentication was done successfully before I start accessing the API methods? If the authentication fails, I want to be able to remove the revoke token from my data store, and try the authentication again, asking for user permission.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few things that can go wrong that you should consider.

1. The user could click accept.   Good No problem here you can check `credential.Token.AccessToken` to see that you got an access token back and can access the API.
2. The user does not click accept but clicks cancle instead.  In this instance an exception is throw.  That is why your code above should probably be in a try catch.  [System.AggregateException] InnerException = {"Error:\"access_denied\", Description:\"\", Uri:\"\""}
3. third option is that the user does nothing in which case your code will hang waiting for the result from the user.   ([Bug report](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/530): still working on a solution for this one)

Now your worry is that if you delete the user in your DatabaseDataStore what will happen.  Well what should happen is the same as if there is a new user.  If your code in DatabaseDataStore is correct the system will detect that it doesn't have this user and will prompt the user again for authentication.   The client library should do this for you, or rather DatabaseDataStore should.   I recommend testing around with user and FileDataStore to see how it works.   If yours is not currently prompting for new authentication when you delete a user from the system then there is something wrong with your DatabaseDataStore.

**Recommendations.**

1. Don't request all those scopes only request what you need.
2. Put your code in a try catch in the event you don't get authentication its going to throw an error you will need to Catch it.
3. Test on AccessToken if you are really worried about it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. However, my scenario is slightly different. I actually do have a try/catch, and it does handle the case when the user clicks on cancel. But in the scenario I described, the user has already authenticated sometime in the past, and now the administrator revokes one of the tokens, but does not delete them from the DB. When the site tries to connect to GA again, it will use the revoked token that it finds in the database. The credential.Token only returns the same revoked token that I initially sent, and doesn't throw an error. http://screencast.com/t/Eum96s3chP

Comment: Your databasedatastore should be handling the admin not fully deleting the refresh token

Comment: Right... but how would the data store know that the token has been revoked? You can revoke a token by calling an URL (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}), but how would the data store check if the token is or is not revoked?

Comment: That is something else I need to test that one the client library should handle that

Comment: Another issue that I notice is that if a user authenticates once using the AnalyticsReadonly scope, and then moves along to another page that tries to authenticate him for the AnalyticsManageUsers scope, the authentication will not give an error, but when I will try any of the user management specific functions, that's when I get the error... Why does it authenticate it in the first place if the scope is different than before?...